# Get Lifecycle state of other apps

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to get the lifecycle state of other apps if they changed. For the first I want to Display a little toast like: "whatsapp, onResume()", if whatsapp is reopen. If I switch to the homescreen after using whatsapp, I want a new toast: "whatsapp, onPause()" and that for every action.